# Finding linked pages to target pages with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am creating a program that, given a starting page and a target page on Wikipedia, navigates from the starting page to the target page via the hyperlinks on each page. For example, if we have the staring page A and target page B, and A links to C, which links to B, we can get from A to B via A -> C -> B.

I have tried using beautiful soup but I am new to web scraping. So far, I have pulled the html from the page and sorted links. The code I have so far is this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Bot")
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
links = bs.find("div", {"id": "bodyContent"}).findAll("a", 
href=re.compile("^(/wiki/)((?!:).)*$"))

for link in links:
    if "href" in link.attrs:
        print(link.attrs["href"])
```

My question is: how can I move from one page to the next through the links on the page?

Comment: Sorry to avoid answering the exact question, but maybe you can accomplish your task more easily by using an existing web-crawler application like `httrack` to download all the linked pages and then just have your parsing code iterate over the downloaded files?

Comment: Just repeat this process for each link untill you reach the destination. This can be done either with an infinite loop or recursion.

Answer (score 2):

In general what you're trying to achieve is not a trivial task. And there are several separate problems that require solution.

**Problem 1:** keeping a track of all links you've already visited and those that you are yet to visit

**Problem 2:** knowing when to stop. If the website you're crawling is quite small then you can hope that after some time you'll simply find all possible links and your crawl will be over.

**Problem 3:** Finding a path based on knowledge of which page is linked to which.
Now to possible solutions:

**Problem 1. Solution A:**
Use a queue and a set. On each step put current page link into a set of visited links, get links from a page, check if any of them are already in a set of visited links, add new links to a queue. Then pick up next link to visit from a queue. Pretty simple approach especially if it's ok for your crawler to take time. This will do everything sequentially. One page after another.

**Problem 1. Solution B:**
Spend 1-2 hours reading about Scrapy and try to implement crawling using Scrapy. It will do multithreading for you as well as will provide tools to find links (in a way similar to how you do it in BeautifulSoup). Advantage: a lot of features are already implemented such as exporting to CSV, JSON for further processing, logging, scraping statistics and so on.

**Problem 2. Solution A.** It depends. If you're looking for any particular path then you can stop as soon as you reach target page and then you can reconstruct path from A to B.

**Problem 2. Solution B.** In case you're looking for the shortest path or ability to find path between A and B for any given A and B then you could limit your crawling by number of hops. Let's say you start on a page A, it has links to B1, B2 and B3. You visit them and give them ordinal number 1. Those B pages have links to C1, C2, C3, C4, C5 - you visit those pages and give them ordinal number 2. You proceed until you reach ordinal number X which means that those pages are X hops away from you starting page. This will ensure that you limit your crawling time.

**Problem 3. Solution A.** When you go to B1, B2, B3 page from page A you "attach a parsel" that says "A". Meaning that those pages can be reached out from page A. Each new page you visit will also have to keep an information about where it can be visited from. Then you use DFS or BFS algorithms to find a path in that set of linked pages.

**Problem 3. Solution B.** Instead of keeping a reference to just previous page you maintain a list. If you visit B from A your B link will have "A" as a path to it. But if you visit C from B you'll add B to existing path and C will contain "A->B" and so on. That means that in the end for each link you'll have a path from A to that link. Works well in case you're interested in any paths from A to any other page.

**Problem 3. Solution C.** For each page when you extract all links from it you build a map where your page is the key and a list of links it contains is the value. It's somewhat the opposite to approach A. Instead of children having references to parent page you have parent page listing its children. In this case you can as well use DFS or WFS algorithms to find path between any two pages.

Comment: I have been reading about scrapy and watching tutorials, trying to keep it as simple as possible just moving  between 2-3 pages. Thank you for the thorough response I will look into each of these problems.

Comment: To find a proper solution I suggest you answer these question:
- are you looking to find any kind (not necessarily shortest) of path between a page A and a page B?
- are you looking to find the shortest path between A and B?
- are you looking to to be able to find the shortest path between any two pages?

Answer (score 2):

**Scraping** a *"huge"* website like Wikipedia has *"huge"* resource demands. I personally don't believe that this is a task that can be done by an individual with limited resources or that this is a question that can be answered definitively, even given the know how, within the word limit of a stack overflow answer. That being said, the following approach in my answer may work on smaller sites with a couple of hundred pages.

*Approach:*

- Define the source and target pages.
- Start crawling from the source page and crawl each link recursively till there is no link in the end page that we have not crawled before.
- Save each crawled page to a dictionary, say `master_link_dict` with `key:value` pairs being as the `crawled page url` :  `links in that page`
- Don't crawl pages we have crawled before. We can check if a url is already in
  the `dictionary.keys()` before crawling the page.
- When we find a page with the `target url` present in it we print the trail and exit. The goal is limited to finding *a* path from `source url` to `target url`

*Code:*

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pprint
source_page='/wiki/Web_Bot'
target_page='/wiki/Computer_Sciences_Corporation'
master_link_dict={}
#initialize trail with target
trail_reverse=[target_page]
def get_links(url):
    html=requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org'+url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")
    links = soup.find("div", {"id": "bodyContent"}).findAll("a", href=re.compile("^(/wiki/)((?!:).)*$"))
    hrefs=[x['href'] for x in links]
    return hrefs

def recursive_crawl(url):
    #don't crawl again if the page has already been crawled
    if url in master_link_dict.keys():
        return
    #get all urls in the current page
    url_list=get_links(url)
    #store as page:[list of urls] in the master dict
    master_link_dict[url]=url_list

    #if target page is found print trail
    if target_page in url_list:
        find_trail(url)

    #crawl all urls of curret page
    for item in url_list:
        recursive_crawl(item)

def find_trail(url):
    #append current url to trail reverse
    trail_reverse.append(url)
    #if current url is the source url print trail and exit
    if url is source_page:
        print('->'.join(trail_reverse[::-1]))
        exit()
    #if current url is in a page, get trail of that page
    for page,url_list in master_link_dict.items():
        if url in url_list:
            find_trail(page)

recursive_crawl(source_page)
```

*Output:*

```
/wiki/Web_Bot->/wiki/Internet_bot->/wiki/Automated_bot->/wiki/Computer_science->/wiki/Computer_Sciences_Corporation
```

*Notes and Disclaimer:*

- The answer is of course quite simplistic and does not account for many edge cases. Eg. What if there is no path between two pages A and B?
- I have answered to the best of my ability but there might be better approaches out there.
- I did not randomly choose the `target url`. I searched for many urls that are 3-6 pages away for testing. The url in the code is one among them.